# $|2- (\sqrt{n^2+4n} - n)| ≥ \frac{1}{10}$

Tags: absolute-value

Any suggestions how to solve the following equation:

> $|2- \sqrt{n^2+4n} + n| ≥ \frac{1}{10}$

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** observe that
$$
\left|2-\sqrt{n^2+4n}+n\right|\ge\frac1{10}|\Longleftrightarrow\\
\left(2-\sqrt{n^2+4n}+n\ge\frac1{10}\right)\vee\left(2-\sqrt{n^2+4n}+n\le-\frac1{10}\right)
$$

Comment: If n is a natural number do you still have to observe: $(2-\sqrt{n^2+4n}+n\le-\frac1{10})$?

Comment: Note that $-\sqrt{n^2+4n}+n=n\left(1-\sqrt{1+\frac4n}\right)=n\frac{-\frac4{n}}{1+\sqrt{1+\frac4n}}=-\frac4{1+\sqrt{1+\frac4n}}\in[-2,-1]$